# Produce repeated left to right movement on sprite without going off screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Recently, a friend sent a basketball game through FB Messenger and I thought it was a pretty cool game. I wanted to recreate it just for fun.

You swipe to "shoot" the ball into the goal. Simple. The goal is stationary from scores 1-10. Moves left to right from scores 11-20. Moves left to right a little faster from scores 21-30. Another friend says that the goal zig zags across the screen at score 31. My highest is 22. The ball also moves along the x-axis at the bottom of the screen in five different positions, randomly.

I was able to get the goal to move either left or right but not a repeated action.

I'm using Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2. Any help would be appreciated. Just want to make sure I'm going in the right direction.

GameScene.swift

```
let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "basketball")
var gameScore: SKLabelNode!
var score: Int = 0 {

    didSet {
        gameScore.text = "Score: \(score)"
    }
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */


    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()



    // Sets the game score BUT it is not displaying on the screen.
    gameScore = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
    gameScore.text = "Score: 0"
    gameScore.position = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 500)
    gameScore.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Left
    gameScore.fontSize = 20

    addChild(gameScore)

    score = 0


    // Create Physics Body that borders the bottom of the screen
    let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)

    // Set friction to 0
    borderBody.friction = 0

    // Set physicsBody to borderBody
    self.physicsBody = borderBody


    // Add the ball to the scene

    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width / 2.0)

    ball.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.4
    ball.xScale = 0.2
    ball.yScale = 0.2
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: 0)
    ball.name = "ball"
    addChild(ball)

    // Commented out so the goal can be stationary
    // moveGoal()

}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{



}



override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
   /* Called when a touch begins */



}


func moveGoal()
{
    let movingGoal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Goal")



    movingGoal.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: 525)
    movingGoal.xScale = 0.7
    movingGoal.yScale = 0.7

    movingGoal.runAction(SKAction.moveByX(size.width, y: 0.0, duration: 5.0))

    addChild(movingGoal)


}

func moveBallAlongXAxis()
{


    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width / 2.0)

    ball.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.4
    ball.xScale = 0.2
    ball.yScale = 0.2
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: 25)
    ball.name = "ball"
    addChild(ball)


}


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)
{


}
```

Comment: What is the question here actually ? Is it shooting/tossing effect ? Goal movement ? Updating sprite movement based on score label (like from the title) ? Or why score label doesn't show up ? You have to concentrate on specific issue because this is not a forum, where people debate about in which direction you can go, but rather give you  (if possible) a solution for a specific problem.

Comment: I do apologize. I'm new to this. I would like to know about how produce the goal movement. It keeps going in either direction.

Comment: To move a node from point a to point b what you are doing already will work. To repeat that, make a sequence. Then repeat that sequence as much as you want using `count` parameter. Associate this action with a key (this will allow you to access it / restart it later). When score reaches certain value, restart this action or change (say modify its speed ) it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Again, I do apologize for my bad etiquette.

Comment: No problem :) I just warned you because questions like this often end up downvoted or put on hold.